# Вопрос по использованию Active Choices Reactive References plugin в Jenkins

Tags: html, jenkins, groovy, ci-cd

Всем привет, я пытаюсь реализовать в Jenkins, используя  Active Choices Reactive References plugin, такую логику, при которой,в первом параметре используется Active Choices Parametr [image: Первый параметр], в зависимости от выбора в котором, во втором Active Choices Reactive Reference Parametr появляется либо html text input, либо html file input [image: Второй параметр]. После чего этот текст, либо файл нужно получить в пайплайне, например

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Demo Active Choices Parameter') {
      steps {
        echo "${services}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

С получением текста из input text, нет проблем. Как я могу получить содержимое файла с такой ситуации?